# Is there a script to automatically fill a VLOOKUP formula in Google Sheets when a new entry is made via Google Forms?

Tags: forms, api, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to get google sheets to populate column *B* with `=VLOOKUP(K:K,Lookup!C:F,4,true)` every time a new entry is made via *google forms*.
At first I tried just having it as a prefilled answer in the form itself but *forms* adds a `'` in front of the `=`, disabling the formula.
Then I have tried numerous scripts.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var sheet = editedRange.getSheet();
  
  // Check if the edited range is in column A
  if (editedRange.getColumn() === 1) {
    var row = editedRange.getRow();
    var value = editedRange.getValue();
    var formulaRange = sheet.getRange(row, 2);
    
    // Check if the corresponding cell in column A is not empty
    if (value !== '') {
      var currentFormula = formulaRange.getFormula();
      var targetFormula = '=VLOOKUP(K:K,Lookup!C:F,4,true)';
      
      // Set the formula in the formula range if it is not already set
      if (currentFormula !== targetFormula) {
        formulaRange.setFormula(targetFormula);
      }
    } else {
      // Clear the formula in the formula range
      formulaRange.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

**Populates column b when typing but not when the form is submitted. **

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var value = e.values[0]; // Assuming the form response is in the first column (column A)
  var formulaRange = sheet.getRange(row, 2); // Corresponding cell in column B
  
  // Check if the corresponding cell in column A is not empty
  if (value !== '') {
    var currentFormula = formulaRange.getFormula();
    var targetFormula = '=VLOOKUP(K:K,Lookup!C:F,4,true)';
    
    // Set the formula in the formula range if it is not already set
    if (currentFormula !== targetFormula) {
      formulaRange.setFormula(targetFormula);
    }
  } else {
    // Clear the formula in the formula range
    formulaRange.clearContent();
  }
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
function autoFillFormula() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

    // Assuming the timestamp is in the first column (column A)
    var timestamp = formResponse.getTimestamp().getTime();

    // Find the corresponding row based on the timestamp in column A
    var row = sheet.createTextFinder(String(timestamp)).findNext().getRow();
    var formulaRange = sheet.getRange(row, 2); // Corresponding cell in column B

    // Check if the cell in column B is empty
    if (formulaRange.getValue() === '') {
      formulaRange.setFormula('=VLOOKUP(K:K,Lookup!C:F,4,true)');
    }
  }
}
```

**Doesn't work**

By now you can probably tell coding is not my thing, and I have been attempting to use ChatGPT to code this.
Hoping for some assistance. :)

Comment: `function onFormSubmit(e)` - Have you created an installable trigger for this function? I processed your script (with a trigger) and it works fine.

Comment: A Google Form normally consists of one or more questions (though not "required"). Therefore when the form is submitted, Column A is **always** a timestamp and Columns B onwards will show the results of the questions answered. Even if a user submits the form and does NOT answer any questions, the Form Response sheet will populate Column A with a timestamp. I mention this because your script assumes `the form response is in the first column (column A)`. As your script is written, even if there is a question response in Column B, your script will overwrite this with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using arrayformula + importrange?

I think you're storing Google Form results in a Google Sheet? If so, you will need an importrange formula to import all Google Form results to the Google Sheet you're working:

```
=importrange("[URL of Google Form results sheet]", "[tab + range of results]")
```

This arrayformula formula can auto populate vlookup when there is a new entry in Google Form:

```
=arrayformula(if(K:K<>"", vlookup(K:K,Lookup!C:F,4,true), "")
```